# Extracting and Organizing Text From A PDF

Tags: python, pdf, screen-scraping, pdf-scraping

I'm currently trying to scrape a bunch of information from PDF pages. I have managed to get some text extracted but haven't been able to extract everything or the format has been difficult to work with. I'm using this example to kind of extract traffic data into a dataframe:

https://www.bts.gov/sites/bts.dot.gov/files/states2020/Alabama.pdf

I want to try and get a dataframe that has all the information organised accordingly. For example, from the information on page 1 I want to have a row that contains the following:

| State | Miles of Public Road | Major Airports | Bridges | Major Water Ports | Miles of Freight Railroad | Number of MPOs | Miles of Waterway |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alabama | 100962 | 9 | 16130 | 2 | 3272 | 14 | 1270 |

This is just an example, I want to extend this for the whole document. I have 2 different forms of code, the first I think is able to get a good amount of information but is very very jumbled and the second doesn't actually contain all the information:

```
import fitz

with fitz.open("US PDF/Alabama.pdf") as doc:
    text = []
    for page in doc:
        text += page.getTextBlocks()
        
# print(text)
```

Second:

```
import PyPDF2

def convert_pdf_to_text (document):
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(document, strict=False)
    number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()

    alltext1=""
    for page_number in range(1,2):
        page = read_pdf.getPage(page_number)
        alltext1 += page.extractText()
        
    return alltext1.replace("\n", "")

convert_pdf_to_text('US PDF/Alabama.pdf')
```

However, I'm not quite sure how to go about going so I can extract all of the data in a good way. Is there any adaptation or recommendation for me to go about doing this?

Cheers

Comment: Where did you find this input data?

Comment: I'm conrfused. I've been looking for the api or document and can't find any for the other countries

Comment: Yeah like I was curious where you found the input data in it's raw format. I tried changing the link of the API but no luck there.

Answer (score 0):

Probably late to answer this. But PyMuPDF has all batteries included to solve your problem: it is just a matter of picking the right text extraction features.

Your file requires to extract text together with all its properties: position information, font size, etc., even text color.

In addition, the file creator has encoded text in non-reading order sequence, so sorting by position is also required.

Having done this, we must find a way to programmatically uncover some structure, by which text has been organized. Looks like a column-based approach leads to the best result.

To find appropriate column borders, I determined the most frequent left border text coordinates and assumed these to be delimiters. For the first page, this looks like so:[image]

Printing the text column-wise yields this result - which is at least a good start for further refinement:

```
---------- page 0 of Alabama.pdf ----------
Alabama
Transportation by the Numbers
Transportation Infrastructure
January 2020

Miles of Public Road
100,962
ROAD CONDITION
Good or Fair
88.1%
Roads with acceptable pavement
ride quality based on International
Roughness Index

Bridges
16,130
BRIDGE DECK AREA CONDITION
Good
37.5%
Fair
60.0%
Poor
2.5%

Miles of Freight Railroad
3,272

Miles of Waterway
1,270

Major Airports
9
Includes Federal Aviation
Administration Part-139 public use
airports.

Major Water Ports
2
Includes ports ranked in the top 150
ports by tonnage in 2017.

Number of MPOs
NUMBER OF MPOs
14
```